# Is it a bug in Ecmascript - /\S/.test(null) returns true?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

Both in Actionscript3 and Javascript these statements give the same result:

```
/\S/.test(null) => true  
/null/.test(null) => true  
/m/.test(null) => false  
/n/.test(null) => true
```

Seems that null value is converted into string "null" in this case.

Is this a known bug in Ecmascript or am I missing something?

Comment: Pro tip: You will never find a bug in a language or a tool. Only super cool programmers do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a bug, but you are right, `null` *coerces* to `'null'` and that behavior is defined on the spec:

1. [`RegExp.prototype.test(string)`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.10.6.3), internally is equivalent to the expression: `RegExp.prototype.exec(string) != null`
2. The [`exec`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.10.6.2) method type converts the first argument to string, using the [`ToString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.8) internal operation (look the Step 1 of the `exec` method).
3. The [`ToString`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.8) internal operation, explicitly returns `"null"` when the input is of 
   type `Null`.

In conclusion, in your examples, the RegExp matchs against the string `'null'`, so the first non-space character, in this case the letter `'n'`.

```
var a = null+''; // 'null'
/\S/.test(a); // true
(null+'').match(/\S/) // ["n"]
```

Answer (score 3):

`null` is an <s>object</s>, and when testing against <s>objects</s> (non-string), its first converted to string, then its giving you that result.

You could try with `/Number/.test(Number)` or `/String/.test(String)`, which would return `true` too.

Probably `String(null)` is being called, which is `'null'`

`String(Number)` will give

```
function Number() {
    [native code]
}
```

and `/function Number/.test(Number)` return `true` too

Comment: Technically `null` is not an object, it's a primitive value, this misconception has been there for years, unfortunately even the `typeof` operator is wrong, since `typeof null == 'object'` which is completely incorrect. Sadly, this was too late to be fixed in the ECMAScript 5th Edition. http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals:typeof