# Length regex tests true on null

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to verify that an input is between 1 and 512 characters long. I'm using the standard length-check regex of `/^.{1,512}$/`. When I run

`/^.{1,512}$/.test(null)`

it returns true. How do I get a length-check regex to fail against null? And why does this test true against null in the first place?

EDIT: Leaving this here since it's more googleable in my case than the earlier question, but per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430578/is-it-a-bug-in-ecmascript-s-testnull-returns-true), the problem is that the regex coerces null into 'null' before testing.

Comment: what should this do for other types, e.g. `123.345`, `false`, `{foo:1}` etc?

Comment: @epascarello is right, that answers my question - null was being coerced into 'null'. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I would test with a regex like this:

```js
var myregexp = /^(?!null).{1,512}$/m;;
```

Comment: This relies on maybe-detecting coercion after the fact – it would fail if fed "null", which is a four-character string and should pass. Fine for my uses though, as "null" isn't a valid value for my field for other reasons!