# Easier way to have RegExp.test() return false for null values?

Tags: javascript

```
let regex = /[a-z]+/;
regex.test('a'); // true
regex.test(''); // false
regex.test(null); // true
regex.test(undefined); // true
```

So based on this link, [Is it a bug in Ecmascript - /\S/.test(null) returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430578/is-it-a-bug-in-ecmascript-s-testnull-returns-true), it looks like the null value is coerced to a string 'null'. WTF? Why on earth is this designed this way? I also can't find any documentation on this behavior. Is there a way to return `false` for null/undefined values (without hardcoding in checks for 'null', etc.)?

Comment: How about e. g. `/,/.test([,,,]) === true` when the argument is not null but not a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument of `RegExp.test()` is expected to be a string. If it isn't, it is converted to a string:

```js
var regex = /\[object Object\]/;
console.log(regex.test({})); // true
```

This is standard behavior in JavaScript. E. g. `"null".replace(null, {}) === "[object Object]"`.

Follow [Check if a variable is a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059147/check-if-a-variable-is-a-string) to check whether or not the argument is a string:

```
if (typeof myVar === 'string' || myVar instanceof String) { ... }
else return false;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're testing a variable, you could do:

```
regex.test(var || '')
```

so that it will default to the empty string if it's not set.

Answer (score 0):

You can override test method.

```
old = regex.test
regex.test = function(str){
    str = str? str: "";
    return old.call(this, str);
}
regex.test(null);  // false
```

One way is to get your expected output is to check the value first and replace it with `""` empty string in case of `null` or `undefined`

```
let regex = /[a-z]+/;
function test (inp){
    return regex.test(inp? inp: '');
}

test(null); // false
test(undefined); // false
```